# How to print array elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to print array element to console using for each loop in javascript. But I am printing something which I am not able to figure out what!

```
 let arr=["1,2,3","iosajah","undefined"];
    for(let data in arr)
    { 
        console.log(data);// prints 4,0,1,2 
        if(typeof data === "undefined")
        {
          //do something

        }
    }
```

console.log(data) prints 4,0,1,2

but I expected it to print each array element

Comment: [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) does not do what you think it does (returns *indexes* in an "arbitrary order"). You might be looking for [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) where you get the element instead of the [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)  where you get the indices of the array.

> **[Difference between `for...of` and `for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Difference_between_for...of_and_for...in)**
>
> Both `for...in` and for...of statements iterate over something. The main difference between them is in what they iterate over.
>
> The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement iterates over the [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of an object, in an arbitrary order.
>
> The `for...of` statement iterates over values that the [iterable object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterables) defines to be iterated over.

```js
let arr = ["1,2,3", "iosajah", "undefined"];
for (let data of arr) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

To get the elements in the order of the indices, you could take a standard [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) and go from the first element to the end of the array.

```js
let arr = ["1,2,3", "iosajah", "undefined"];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: @shadoe2020, sorry, i didn't know, that you invented the `for` statement with a counter as index. it's time to thank you for this.

Comment: Posted it before you did, and you shamelessly felt it still needed a 2nd post. Eh whatever.

Comment: really a dv? come on.

Comment: Yes you copied my solution and you also copied Dupocas's. Thus the post is sloppy and requires no effort, as per the rules of a down vote.

Comment: please have a look to the time of the answer, and then compare it with the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

for in loop is used to iterate through object literals, but since Arrays (and everything else) are actually objects in JavaScript you are actually logging the keys of the Array object which are the index values.

You want to use `forEach`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```
let arr=["1,2,3","iosajah","undefined"];

arr.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed `data` to `key` since that is what the `for... in...` syntax produces: the key of the object (which may be an Array) during the iteration.  You should not have printed a `4` at all as this typescript playground shows: [Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20arr%3D%5B%221%2C2%2C3%22%2C%22iosajah%22%2C%22undefined%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for(let%20data%20in%20arr)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(data)%3B%2F%2F%20prints%204%2C0%2C1%2C2%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(typeof%20data%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22undefined%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fdo%20something%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20)

```
 let arr=["1,2,3","iosajah","undefined"];
 for(let key in arr)
 { 
     console.log(arr[key]);// prints 0,1,2 
     if(typeof arr[key] === "undefined")
     {
          //do something

     }
 }
```

If you want to iterate over an array the more typical way to do it is using the `.forEach` syntax.

```
let arr=["1,2,3","iosajah","undefined"];
arr.forEach((element, index, arr) => {
    console.log(element, index);
    if (typeof element === "undefined") {
        //do something
    }
})
```

It also looks like you probably are intending to look for the string `undefined` in the array and if that is the case then you don't want to check the `typeof`, you just want to compare the string value:

```
if (element === "undefined") {

}
```

The `typeof element` will never be a string of value `"undefined"` in this example.

Comment: The downside to this is that the order of iteration is arbitrary and not guaranteed to be in array order. Also, you should explain why this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your For/In statement is to traverse properties of an object. If you check the length of your array and step through it. We want values, rather than properties. You can print it this way.

```
let arr=["1,2,3","iosajah","undefined"];
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
      {
       console.log(arr[i]);
       if(typeof data === "undefined"){
       //do something
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`for in` loops over enumerable property names of an object, you are printing the indexes of the array. If you want to iterate over the values use one of the approaches:

```
for(let value of array)
```

Or

```
Object.keys(array).map(key => console.log(array[key]))
```